# Why is an open interval not a compact set?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I learned that every compact set is closed and bounded; and also that an open set is usually not compact.

How to show that a concrete open set, for example the interval $(0,1)$, is not compact? I tried to show that $(0,1)$ has no finite sub cover.

Comment: If you define a compact set to be closed and bounded, then I don't see what the question is.

Comment: Are you using the "every open cover has a finite sub-cover" definition of compactness?

Comment: I just want to know why a compact set is closed whereas an open set is not?

Comment: The definition of compact in Euclidean space is closed and bounded. If that's not satisfactory, the "real" definition of compact is "every open cover has a finite subcover." Open sets in Euclidean space do not satisfy this property.

Comment: why don't open intervals satisfy that? This is what I want to know.

Comment: Actually, it would be good if you explained the question. It is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: @CameronBuie In non-Hausdorff spaces compacts can be non-closed.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy for non-Hausdorff spaces, such subsets are referred to as "quasi-compact", whereas "compact" is reserved to apply only to Hausdorff spaces.  At least, this is the convention in algebraic geometry.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I see, so it's just a notation collision. In my course of functional analysis they were all called compact. And then, given the properties of the topology, we derived the properties of compact sets.

Comment: @Ommonmnomnom Yes, it is a convention in algebraic geometry. However, the standard topology book (Munkres) use compact without differentiation.

Comment: I just want to know why (0,1) has no finite sub cover?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: True, not all spaces are KC spaces. Erroneous comment deleted.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think the following may be a source of confusion: the statement "$(0,1)$ has no finite sub cover" doesn't make any sense.  You first have to *choose* a cover of $(0,1)$ by open sets.  Then this may or may not have a finite sub-cover.

If $(0,1)$ were compact, any such cover would (by the definition of compact in terms of open covers) have to have a finite subcover.  In fact, $(0,1)$ is not compact, and so what this means is that we can find *some* cover of $(0,1)$ by open sets which does not have a finite subcover.

Omnomnomnom gives an example of such a cover in their answer, and there are lots of others; here's one: the cover $\{U_2, \ldots, U_n , \ldots\}$ where $U_n = (1/n, 1-1/n).$

Here is a cover which is finite, and hence *does* have a finite subcover (namely, itself): $\{(0,1)\}$.

Here is another: $\{(0,1/2), (1/3,1)\}$.

Here is an infinite cover which admits a finite subcover $\{(0,1), (0,1/2), 
\ldots, (0,1/n) , \ldots \}$.

Hopefully these examples help to clarify what the definition of compactness in terms of finite subcovers is about.

Comment: Why isn't the cover $U_n$ an example that shows that closed intervals are not compact as well? Doesn't ${U_n}_{n=2}^{\infty}$ cover the closed set [0,1] when you take the limit of $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @TheCodingWombat No, neither $0$ nor $1$ is contained in any $U_n$, thus the family doesn't cover the closed interval $[0,1]$. We have $$\bigcup_{n = 2}^{\infty} U_n = (0,1)\,.$$

Answer (score 6):

To be sure, there exist sets that are open and closed and bounded.  For example, if we take the space $X = [0,1] \cup [2,3] \cup [4,5]$ under the typical topology of $\mathbb{R}$, then $[2,3]$ is a closed, open, compact proper subset of $X$.

As for open intervals, consider the example of $X = (0,1)$.  Defining $U_n = (1/n,1)$, we note that $\{U_1,U_2,\dots\}$ is an open cover of $X$ (since $X \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$) that has no finite subcover.

Answer (score 6):

(Assuming you're talking about $\Bbb{R}^1$)

Consider the open interval $(a,b)$. Let $d=|b-a|/2$, and let $c=(a+b)/2$, the midpoint of $(a,b)$. Take the collection of open intervals: $\{(c-\frac{n}{n+1}d,c+\frac{n}{n+1}d)\}_{n=1}^\infty$. This collection covers $(a,b)$ (its union equals $(a,b)$), but no finite sub-collection covers $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth:

A subset of the euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. This is a possible definition of compactness of sets like these.

Regarding the concepts of open, closed, bounded: You will have to look up their definitions. Some examples of subsets of $\mathbb R$:

- The empty set is open, closed and bounded.
- The set $\mathbb R$ is open, closed and not bounded.
- The interval $(0,1)$ is open, not closed, bounded.
- The interval $(0,\infty)$ is open, not closed, not bounded.
- The interval $[0,1]$ is not open, closed, bounded.
- The interval $[0,\infty)$ is not open, closed, not bounded.
- The interval $[0,1)$ is not open, not closed, bounded.
- The set $\{0\}\cup (1,\infty)$ is not open, not closed, not bounded.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confused about the concept of (sub)cover. Let me see if I can clear it up for you.

Suppose we have a set $X$ with some topology on $X,$ a set $A\subseteq X,$ and a set $\mathcal C$ *of subsets* of $X.$

- We say that $\mathcal C$ "covers $A$" (or "is a cover of $A$") if every point of $A$ lies in some $\mathcal C$-set (*i.e.*: $A\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal C$).
- We say that $\mathcal C$ "is an open cover of $A$" if $\mathcal C$ is a cover of $A$ consisting entirely of open sets.
- If $\mathcal C$ is a cover of $A,$ then a subcover is some $\mathcal S\subseteq\mathcal C$ such that $\mathcal S$ covers $A$.

It is inappropriate, then, to talk about "subcovers of $(0,1)$" because $(0,1)$ is not a set of subsets of the real line.

Let's consider $X=\Bbb R$ (with the usual topology), $A=(0,1).$ Now, there *are* open covers of $(0,1)$ with finite subcovers--for example, given any collection $\mathcal C'$ of open subsets of $\Bbb R,$ we have that $\mathcal C:=\mathcal C'\cup\bigl\{(0,1)\bigr\}$ is an open cover of $(0,1),$ and $\bigl\{(0,1)\bigr\}$ is a finite subcover. This is not enough to make $(0,1)$ compact, though. For that, we would need to know that **every** open cover of $(0,1)$ admits a finite subcover, which is not the case. Consider for example $$\mathcal C:=\left\{\left(\frac1{n+1},1\right)\mid n\text{ is a positive integer}\right\}.\tag{$\star$}$$ Suppose $\mathcal S\subseteq\mathcal C$ is finite. If $\mathcal S$ is empty, then it is clearly not a cover of $(0,1).$ Otherwise, there is some positive integer $m$ such that every element of $\mathcal S$ is a subset of $\left(\frac1m,1\right)$ (why?), so that $$\bigcup\mathcal S\subseteq\left(\frac1m,1\right)\subsetneq(0,1),$$ and so $\mathcal S$ does not cover $(0,1).$ Thus the open cover $\mathcal C$ defined in $(\star)$ has no finite subcover, and so $(0,1)$ is not compact.

---

In many topologies, open sets *can* be compact. In fact, the empty set is *always* compact.

Also, any topology with $\subseteq$-minimal non-empty open sets will have open compact subsets. For example, consider the topology on the real line having the empty set and the supersets of $(0,1)$ as open subsets of the real line. This is not the usual topology, of course, but you can check that

- arbitrary unions of open subsets of the real line are again open subsets of the real line,
- finite (in fact, arbitrary) intersections of open subsets are again open, and
- the empty set and real line are open.

So, this is indeed a topology on the real line. In this topology, $(0,1)\cup F$  is open, compact, and non-closed for any finite subset $F$ of the real line.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! Could you give an example of a topology where opens sets are compact?

Comment: @Konstantin: You mean other than the example I gave in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In the general realm of topology, these concepts are not really too related to each other. For example, in a finite set with the discrete topology every set is compact which are both open and closed. A compact set is not guaranteed to be closed unless you are in a Hausdorff space. In a topological set with the trivial topology, everything is compact, and here the only closed sets are the empty set and the set itself.