# Why we need to prove a set K is compact of X(metric space) if X is always open and closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I think given any subset K in metric space X, K can be covered by X. Since X is open, K only need 1 open set to cover it. I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

A subset $K$ of a metric space $X$ is compact if for **every** open cover of $K$, we can find a finite subcover.

The open cover $\{X\}$ is just one open cover, and it does indeed have a finite subcover. But the definition says we need any arbitrary open cover of $K$ to have a finite subcover. So just checking $\{X\}$ will not suffice.

Conversely, to show $K$ is not compact, we need only exhibit one example of an open cover that does not have a finite subcover.

Comment: Can you give me one example for K is not compact in X ? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $K = \mathbb{Z}$.  Think about an open cover where each open set contains just one integer.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ compact is equivalent to closed and bounded (not true in general metric spaces though!). So any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is not closed or is unbounded will not be compact. For instance, $\mathbb{R}$ itself is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$. Nor is $(0,1)$. See [Why is an open interval not a compact set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609217/why-is-an-open-interval-not-a-compact-set).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misreading the definition of "compact". It says that *every* open cover has a finite subcover. Your question notes the obvious fact that there happens to be one particular open cover that is finite.

Answer (score 0):

A topological set $K$ is called compact if each of its open covers has a finite subcover. An open cover is a collection of subsets $U_i \subset K$ such that the union $\cup_i U_i = K$.

In your example, $X$ is not a subset of $K$, which is mandatory from the definition.

Furthermore, finding a single finite open cover is not enough: According to the definition, a set $X$ is compact if from ANY open cover has a finite subcover.